# Peak Sharping of multi-signal data

Tags: signal-analysis, python, peak-detection, preprocessing

I have multi-signal data and as a processing step want to apply peak sharping of signal as shown in fig below.

is there any way I can achieve this in python ?

Literature :[Paper 1](https://www.scirp.org/html/28309.html)(Peak sharping section ) [Paper 2](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/%7Exzhang/publications/zhang-gensips02.pdf)

Algorithm in Literature

$D_{K+1} = D_{K} + \lambda(D_{0} - h\bigotimes_{}^{}D_{K})$

$\lambda$ : Relaxation constant

$h$ : Gaussian point spread function

**Goal**

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify a bit where you have trouble ? What's preventing you from just taking the algorithm from the paper and implementing it in Python ?

Comment: I have some issue in implementing that algorithm and I was thinking there might be an easy solution for it

Comment: My guess is that your signal has certain amount of samples, and what you see in the original spectrum is the dft of it. You can multiply the signal with a different kind of windows so in the Freq domain you get a change due to the convolution been done by the multiplication. Try different window and hope for better results

Comment: I think I am not using the correct values for $λ $: Relaxation constant and $h $: Gaussian point spread function, if you could let me know how i can determine them